# measure how far I have run with lua

Tags: gps, lua, location

How do I measure how far I have run with **lua** program? Preferably from gps locations. I have both longitude and latitude.

Comment: In what context? On a smartphone? I'd love to help you out, but add some details, your question's too vague.

Comment: yes it is a app on smartphone and i use conora sdk

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's like a pedometer, but instead of measuring steps, it measures distance? My first instinct would be to use the Pythagorean theorem. And execute it every X ms if you need total distance run and not just the distance from point A to point B.

Comment: Exactly! It is an app which keeps track of how fast you drive and if you drive too fast it will give you a message .... But it should also measure how far you have driving and that is what I have problems with.

Comment: thank you so much! But how can i get this code to a text element on the screen?

Comment: The closure returns the total distance. So you can just do a `print(myodometer(long, lat))` or whatever function you use to put something on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a closure along with the pythagorean theorem to do so:

```
function odometer(curx, cury)
    local x = curx or 0
    local y = cury or 0
    local total = 0
    return function(newx, newy)
        local difx = math.abs(newx - x)
        local dify = math.abs(newy - y)
        total = total + math.sqrt(difx * difx + dify * dify)
        x, y = newx, newy
        return total
    end
end
```

At the startup of your applicationsd, you would call `odometer` and pass in your current longitude and latitude (or it will default to 0):

```
myodometer = odometer(longitude, latitude)
```

Afterwards, you set up your application to call `myodometer` every, say 1000 ms, while passing in your new longitude and latitude:

```
myodometer(newlongitude, newlatitude)
```

[Here's a link to Lua closures](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html)

Comment: The longitude diff and latitude diff are not equal to difx and dify required for Pythagorean theorem.  More complex [formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) must be used.